# CSS Animation not triggering when class is added

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to set up a CSS animation to trigger when I sett a class to a div via jquery. I tried to follow [this](https://www.florin-pop.com/blog/2019/03/css-pulse-effect/) tutorial, but basically instead of the animation always running, I wanted to trigger it via a JQuery/JS onclick function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".settings-container").click(function() {
    $(".settings-container").addClass("transform");
  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 Var(--search_secondary); */
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px Var(--search_secondary); */
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 Var(--search_secondary); */
  }
}

.settings-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 2vw;
  height: 5vh;
  width: 5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: Var(--menu_highlight);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 Var(--search_secondary);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.settings-container .transform {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 Var(--search_secondary);
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.SDot1,
.SDot2,
.SDot3 {
  width: 4px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="settings-container">
  <div class="SDot1"></div>
  <div class="SDot2"></div>
  <div class="SDot3"></div>
</div>
```

I have been able to confirm that the @keyframes pulse works once I add it directly to the `.settings-container` class, and I see that the `transform` class is being added once the container is clicked. I do not see the animation being kicked off once that class is called, and when inspecting via chrome tools do not see the CSS for the transform class being changed to include the transform class once it has been added. Is there some small connection that I am missing?

Comment: remove between two class space like this and check agian:  .settings-container.transform

Comment: so you want sdot1 sdot2 sdot3 to blink on a click of a button

Comment: same div multiple class, You can't use space

Comment: Please clarify the question. There is no need to add animation to `setting-container` if you want your dot to have pulse animation you should add animation in sdot1,2,3 div. Please let me know what you want to achieve.

Comment: @DelowarHossen Wow yeah I guess that worked... I didnt realize that that was an interaction that happened... I have been using a space between the two classes up until this point and it seems to have worked with most things. Do you know when to use a space vs when not to use a space? or is there a resource that I can look at?

Comment: @Ashishsah, I am looking to add an effect to the whole container that is surrounding `SDot1`, `SDot2`, & `SDot3`. So when you click the container (Which is a circle) there is a pulse effect around the whole container.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".settings-container").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("transform");
  });
});
```

```css
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 Var(--search_secondary); */
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px Var(--search_secondary); */
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0.95);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 Var(--search_secondary); */
  }
}

.settings-container {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 2vw;
  height: 5vh;
  width: 5vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: Var(--menu_highlight);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 Var(--search_secondary);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.settings-container .transform {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 Var(--search_secondary);
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}

.SDot1,
.SDot2,
.SDot3 {
  width: 4px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="settings-container">
  <div class="SDot1"></div>
  <div class="SDot2"></div>
  <div class="SDot3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.